# Help in plugging equation in arbritrary current source LTSpice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, formula-derivation

I cannot plug in the following equation and parameters in arbitrary current source. Any help would very appreciated. ltspice cannot read my parameters.[image].

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Read this. You use a thing called an arbitrary source.

http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/B_Arbitrary_behavioral_voltage_or_current_sources_.htm

[image]

Comment: Can you post some more information from the link? Link-only answers break as soon as the link does.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you web query "ltspice arbitrary source" you get that link.

You can place the arbitrary current source from the compponent library dialog. Just type "bi" and you get it. Replace the equation, which is default "I=F(...)" with your equation. Just replace the F(...) part. for spice, the time variable is just "time". Good luck.

Comment: Web sites frequently go down, change their directory structures, or change their domain name. The LTWiki link is valid now, but who knows whether it will work five years from now? That's why it's important for answers to contain detailed information, not just links. The information in your comment should be part of your answer. I can help you edit your answer if you'd like.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Answer (score -1):

I have not seen any circuit simulator (and I've used many) that will let you define your (Current)source  with complex formulas like these.
A polynomial or piecewise-lineair source is what is commonly available in circuit simulators.

I suggest entering these formulas in Matlab, or Octave (free Matlab clone)
to visualize I(t).